# Creating AR for room acoustic simulation

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to do a project on room acoustic simulation which I have been so obsessed about how to draw lines before. My project adviser wants me to use only one marker for the AR but there are so many lines I need to create and probably one marker won't be enough e.g. If your trying to look at the lines which is on the ceiling of the room, the camera can no longer detect the marker.

So basically I just wanna know other people opinions on is there any other way to create lines of this simulation without using multiple markers? Because using multiple markers for this AR simulation would be insane as there are lots of line to draw already.

Sorry about the image, they didn't let me to post so here's the link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0I1h.jpg

Answer (score 0):

With Vuforia you have a thing called **Extended Tracking** [Info here](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Training/Extended-Tracking). It allows you to keep track of your augmented objects even when their markers are no longer in sight. Extended Tracking is automatically enabled for all targets when the Positional Device Tracker is enabled. It is not perfect, it depends on the size of your augmentation but it may do the job.

Comment: Thanks for the resource, I just tried that but I can't really see difference between using the positional device tracker and not using. I followed the step on this link, https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Configuring-Rotational-Tracking-in-Unity.html but it seems my version doesn't have fusion mode option at all even though I tried to add the code inside the DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs but the error came up.

Comment: saying that Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs(125,53): error CS1061: Type `Vuforia.VuforiaConfiguration.DeviceTrackerConfiguration' does not contain a definition for `FusionMode' and no extension method `FusionMode' of type `Vuforia.VuforiaConfiguration.DeviceTrackerConfiguration' could be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Comment: I'm sorry it's been a while since I last used this technology, I can't really help you with that. It seems like you are missing som imports but I couldn't tell which.